# Unexpected start downloading while HttpResponse returns two strings

Tags: python, django

I wrote a code for setting path for import and export files:

```
def setPath(*args):
    abs_path = os.path.dirname(__file__) #/path/to/dir/
    root_dir = os.path.split(abs_path)[0] #/path/to/root_of_project/
    imp_file_path = "files/links.txt"
    exp_file_path = "files/html_data"
    abs_imp_file_path = os.path.join(root_dir, imp_file_path) # abs_path to file
    abs_exp_file_path = os.path.join(root_dir, exp_file_path)
    return HttpResponse(abs_exp_file_path)
```

It works good, but if I try return both 'abs_imp_file_path' and 'abs_exp_file_path', browser starts to download a file named "download" (without extension) with value of 'abs_exp_file_path' . Why it happens? Please explain where I'm wrong.

Answer (score 0):

`HttpResponse` just returns a string in your case, that´s why you see this value as download... Normally this should be a fully fledged HTML (document) response.

Please have a look at the django documentation for HttpResponseObjects (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/request-response/#httpresponse-objects)

Comment: Thanks for reply but I can't find suitable HttpResponse method to return multiple strings. Could you please explain some more?

Comment: Honestly I quite do not understand what you are trying to do... So please elaborate what your view does or should do...

Comment: I really would like to help you, but I still do not understand what you are trying to achieve... Maybe someone else can jump in here?

Comment: If I need to import file to work with in my next function I refer to one path that above function  returns, otherwise I refer to another path. Something like that. Perhaps it is a silly idea but I just wanted to make separate function to set two pathes.